# c++ system call gives error is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I try the following command
`system("\"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\MyProgram\\MyProgram\\MyProgram.exe\"");`

and the output I get is

`'C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command,`

whats going on?

I use `\\` for path delimeters, I used `\"` for double quotes to catch the whitespace and at the beginning and end.
everything prints well (using puts/printf)\and if if I copy what i printed to console it works.

why doesn't it work?

Comment: found it seems that double `\"` is needed
see:
http://superuser.com/questions/713074/how-do-i-escape-spaces-in-command-line-in-windows

Comment: I'd recommend to use [raw string literals](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal) to make your life easier.